# Showing error Request entity too large! The POST method does not allow the data transmitted, or the data volume exceeds the capacity limit

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using xampp on mac o/s , and i am trying to upload the file which is 1.7 Gb but on my local it was showing me the error 413 file too large, then I changed the `post_max_size to 5G` in php.ini in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini`, but still it is showing me the same error, like it has no effect on it, then i went and tried
`echo ini_get('post_max_size');`
it shows 5G.
I also tried to set memory_limit to 5G , still same error.
I also checked the localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php there it was showing the post_max_size 5G
already tried changing the values of

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
memory_limit
max_execution_time
max_input_time
Please help!
```

just want to know how to increse the post max size properly on mac.

Comment: I’d go for FTP instead of posting it

Comment: What's the value for `upload_max_filesize`? Also make sure you restart Apache after you make these ini changes.

Comment: FTP is not an option, I am actually trying to upload the file to all in one in one wp migration in Wordpress. There i have to upload it. @LelioFaieta

Comment: That is also 5G @James , and yes i have restarted apache after every change. 
if you have the mac and you try to install the xampp, and then try to upload the large file , you will be able to regenerate the error. Thanks

Comment: The error is probably coming directly from the Apache server, before it even starts to execute any of your PHP code. First thing you should look at is the [`LimitRequestBody`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) directive.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for helping me out here. So, the problem was with the LimitRequestBody in httpd.conf file which was effecting the whole process of uploading the file. I will update the code in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was with the value LimitRequestBody in httpd.conf file located at the position /Applications/xampp/xammppfiles/etc/httpd.conf ,
Apache was stoping the large file to upload.
I had to add the code:

```
   <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
    #adding this code below line
    LimitRequestBody 2147483648 #2GB
   </Directory>
```

"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs" -> this must be the path where htdocs folder is located in xampp.

in addition don't forget to add the following code in .htaccess to increase the size limit.

```
 php_value upload_max_filesize 42800M
php_value post_max_size 42800M
php_value memory_limit 245600M
php_value max_execution_time -1
php_value max_input_time -1
```

OR inside php.ini file search each of them one by one and then increase their size.